# Using Javascript to change Raphael ID property to display nothing

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, raphael

I'm wondering if it's possible to come up with a Javascript that will not display the HTML 5 Demo logo?

This problem only occurs in IE8 as Windows have their own ways of rendering an interactive vector image. All the browsers don't have that.

If you view the linked image, the map has the same class name for all the regions. If I put a CSS code such as **.rvml { display: none; }** the whole map will just disappear along with the HTML Demo logo. Again, this only happens on IE8 not on any other browsers. I think IE9 and above aren't affected as this type of vector rendering engine is outdated.

So with the help of Firebug Lite for IE8, I found that it has a unique ID, but this also comes with a unique property called **raphaelid** as you can see on the linked screenshot below.

**http://i146.photobucket.com/albums/r263/ZweihanderZ/map_zpsf593b44b.jpg**

Additionally, you may view the website too: **http://www.planet.nu/dev/debt-burden-responsive/map.html**

Comment: Don't think I understand the actual question.

Comment: Problem has been solved. My colleague made changes to the map.js. Cheers!